# How to calculate arctan in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

NetLogo doesn't seem to define a function for arctan? I am correct or does there exist any function for this. Is there any library which has this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has the more practical two-argument [`atan`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#atan) function. It's like the [`atan2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function you see in a lot of programming languages. Note that it uses NetLogo's angle orientation, so everything is flipped around the 45º line (up is 0º, right is 90º). If you want standard `atan2`, use `atan y x` instead of `atan x y`.